# How does AlarmManager works when app killed

Tags: android

My app set `PenddingIntent` in `AlarmManager`.I kown this `PenddingIntent` will be keep in `AlarmManger` and the `PendingIntentRecord` is saved in `ActivityManagerService`.So when my app
be killed，it has nothing to do with the AlarmManager calling the `ActivityManagerService` do
the `penddingIntent` in the future.But the fact is not.I find the `logcat` would output the log

```
03-13 09:32:43.149      462-475/? I/AlarmManager﹕ Remove <my package> from mIntentHisRW
03-13 09:32:43.159      462-475/? I/AlarmManager﹕ record removed
```

I just can't find where does the log produced in source code.And How does `AlarmManager` works when app killed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue while using adb to check if your alarms are persisting in AlarmManager? Killing an app should really have no affect on it.

Comment: After killing the app, i found the alarms my app set disappeared.And the reason i found why could see the below comments. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is killed by the user(stop app in the settings),the Android OS will think that it is the user＇s  desire that this app should not be working any more.So the Android OS will remove the AlarmManager record.

I have not found this log too,maybe your ROM＇s  developers added it.

Comment: yes,you(@tianwei) are right.Something is different between being killed by user and being stopped by crash.I viewed the source code ActivityManagerService.java and seen when being killed by user would call the method forceStopPackageLocked which broadcasts Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED and AlarmManagerService receives it and do removing alarms.But if being killed by crash,AlarmManager will go on with the penddingintents in the future.

Comment: Yes,in the method broadcastIntentLocked,it contains the sentences:  if (curt.activityInfo.packageName.equals(skipPackage)) {
                                receivers.remove(it); it--;NT--;}  This method would be called by forceStopPackageLocked which method is called by forceStopPackageLocked or clearApplicationUserData.

Comment: And here is the official docs "Broadcast Action: The user has restarted a package, and all of its processes have been killed. All runtime state associated with it (processes, alarms, notifications, etc) should be removed. Note that the restarted package does not receive this broadcast. The data contains the name of the package." ---So how do we set our alarms again on this broadcast if we want them maintained?

Comment: you should reset the alarm when your app first stated.Just like you first install it.